# Is there a way to do WhitespaceBefore in CheckStyle?

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

In Checkstyle (I'm using the maven plugin), I can use WhitespaceAfter to ensure whitespace after specific tokens.

Is there a way to use something that would have the effect of WhitespaceBefore? I want to enforce whitespace before some open-parens (open parens for if and for, for example) and some left curly braces.

I suppose WhitespaceAfter for for and if tokens would work too but I can't figure that out either.

Thanks!

Comment: As you describe it, this seems impossible to me. But maybe if you can give a concrete code example, we can find some way to do it.

Comment: Say we have method foo:

    `public void foo(int x, int y) {

    ...

    }`

I want to enforce a space before the open curly brace.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, I understand the question like this: *How can I enforce a space before the opening curly brace in this code:*

```
public void foo(int x, int y) {   ...   }
//                           ^--- here
```

This is in fact possible via the [WhitespaceAround](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_whitespace.html#WhitespaceAround) check. Just make sure the `LCURLY` token is set. That's the default if you don't set any tokens.

A possible catch is that *WhitespaceAround* enforces whitespace *after* the curly brace, too. But in the case of a left curly brace, that's almost always there anyway, at least in the form of a line break.

Comment: I would use this, but there's some (like only 2) cases when I want there to not be a space after the left curly :(

Comment: Ok, please tell us which ones they are. There *is no* WhitespaceBefore check, so you will either have to take a workaround or leave it be.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant before the left curly. I guess this means even the WhitespaceBefore wouldn't work for me if it did exist because I only want it in some cases not all. :(